# How can I update my events table using update function?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to update my events table in laravel but since i'm fairly new with php and laravel I have no idea how to do it I can already store my data in db just need to find a way to update it. Also I have an error "Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.)

My blade file

```
<div class="table-responsive">
   <table id="default_order" class="table table-striped border display" style="width:100%">
      <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Event Name</th>
            <th>Start Time</th>
            <th>End Time</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Manage</th>

          </tr>
      </thead>
          <tbody>
              @foreach ($event as $ev)
                 <tr>
                   <td>
                     {{$ev->event_name}}
                   </td>
                   <td>
                     {{$ev->event_start}}
                   </td>
                   <td>
                     {{$ev->event_finish}}
                   </td>

                   <td>
                     {{$ev->event_status}}
                   </td>

                   <td>
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data- 
                     toggle="modal" data-target="#eventModal{{$event->id}}" 
                     data-whatever="{{$event->id}}">  View</button>

                     <div class="modal fade" id="eventModal{{$event->id}}" 
                     tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- 
                     labelledby="eventModalLabel{{$event->id}}">

                     <div class="modal-dialog modal modal-dialog-centered" 
                     role="document">

                     <div class="modal-content">

                     <div class="modal-header">

                       <h4 class="modal-title" id="eventModalLabel{{$event- 
                       >id}}">Event Details:</h4>

                        <button type="button" class="close" data- 
                        dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria- 
                        hidden="true">&times;</span></button>

                     </div>


                    <div class="modal-body">

                      <form method="POST" action="{{ route('event.update', 
                      $event->id) }}">

                      @method('PATCH')

                      @csrf

                      <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-md-5">

                            <div class="form-group">

                               <label for="event-name" class="control- 
                               label">Event Name:</label>

                               <input type="text" class="form-control" 
                               name="event_name" value="{{$event- 
                               >event_name}}">

                           </div>



                     </div>


                    <div class="col-md-5">

                       <div class="form-group">

                          <label for="event-start" class="control-label">Start 
                          Time:</label>

                             <input type="text" class="form-control" 
                             name="event_start" value="{{$event- 
                             >event_start}}">

                       </div>

                    </div>



                </div>


            <div class="row">

              <div class="col-md-5">

                <div class="form-group">

                   <label for="event-finish" class="control-label">End Time: 
                   </label>

                    <input type="email" class="form-control" 
                    name="event_finish" value="{{$event->event_finish}}">

               </div>

              </div>

            </div>


          </div>



     <div class="modal-footer">

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data- 
        dismiss="modal">Close</button>

        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Edit">

     </div>

    </form>

  </div>

 </div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

I have a problem with this specific line

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data- 
                     toggle="modal" data-target="#eventModal{{$event->id}}" 
                     data-whatever="{{$event->id}}">  View</button>
```

because it outputs an error "Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.)"

The migrations table

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('events', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('event_name');
            $table->string('event_desc')->nullable();

            //0 = Ongoing; 1 = Upcoming; 2 = Finished;
            $table->integer('event_status')->nullable();
            $table->dateTime('event_start');
            $table->dateTime('event_finish');

            $table->integer('evcat_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        });

        Schema::table('events', function($table) {
            $table->foreign('evcat_id')->references('id')->on('event_categories')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        });

    }
```

EventController update function

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $validator = $request->validate([
            'event_name' => 'required',
            'event_start' => 'required',
            'event_finish' => 'required',

        ]);



        return redirect()->route('event.sched');
        /**
        $ev = event::find($id);

        $ev->event_name = $request->input("event_name");

        $ev->save();

        Session::flash('success', 'Event successfully updated.');



        return redirect()->route('event.sched');
        **/
    }
```

Event Model

```
class Event extends Model
{

    //
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    public function eventCategory()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\EventCategory', 'evcat_id');
    }
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
    }
    protected $fillable = [
        'event_name', 'event_desc', 'event_status', 'event_start', 'event_finish', 'evcat_id', 'user_id',
    ];

    public $timestamps = false;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `foreach loop` you name the variable `$ev` yet in the piece of code you supplied you reference to `$event`

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data- 
                 toggle="modal" data-target="#eventModal{{$ev->id}}" 
                 data-whatever="{{**$ev**->id}}">  View</button>

<input type="email" class="form-control" 
                name="event_finish" value="{{$ev->event_finish}}">

<input type="text" class="form-control" 
                             name="event_start" value="{{$ev- 
                             >event_start}}">
```

This should solve the id error you've been getting.

As for the update method (I'm not use wat your route looks like) it should assign the model (using [route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-model-binding)) So you can do something like:

```
public function update(Request $request, Event $event)
{
    $validator = $request->validate([
        'event_name' => 'required',
        'event_start' => 'required',
        'event_finish' => 'required',

    ]);
    $event->update($request->all());

    return redirect()->route('event.sched');
}
```

Also take a look at [From request validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#form-request-validation), using this you can use the same validator for the create and update methods without defining the validator in the controller method.